# Rest API: How should the filter params send to API in case query based on nested resource

Tags: rest, api

I have two entities Properties and Bookings.

I need to know the URL structure in case I'm filtering the properties base on query on bookings.

In my case I need to get the properties which are free (not occupied) at specific date.

Can it be

```
api/properties/free/{date}
```

Or

```
api/properties/bookings?bookingDate!='1-1-2017'
```

Or

```
api/properties?bookingDate!='1-1-2017'
```

it seems for me that the last one is the more appropriate but the filter is on the bookings not on the properties which is not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook Graph API has a interesting way of doing nested queries by using a strategy of fields filter.

The fields filter it´s a way of filter specific fields or nested fields of a rouserce. They also create a standard way to inform functions for every selected field like: limit or equal.

Your request would be something like this:

```
GET /api/properties?fields=bookings{bookingDate.notEqual('1-1-2017')}
```

For more information about Facebook´s GraphAPI:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/

Comment: This structure requires query or where condition generator besides to projection.

Comment: This structure requires a DSL to parse this fields attribute. You can try a simpler query DSL using jSON: ...?q={"bookings": {"bookingDate": {"eq": "2017-01-01"}}}